# Naive question about notation for unusual products of entries of matrix with rank-3 tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I am trying to do a computation and I'm not very good with actually using tensors for computations.

I have some $(n\times n)$ matrices $A = [a_{ij}]$ and $B = [b_{ij}]$ and some kind of rank-3 tensor $T = [T_{ijk}]$, where again $i,j$ and $k$ go from $1$ to $n$. In the course of the computation I have various terms with an odd number of repeated indices. Is there any good way to think about them or express them?

e.g. I have an expression like
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}T_{kkj}.
$$
Somehow one would like this to be the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of something, but is that actually the case or is it just some weird combination of entries? There are three $k$ indices in the sum and that seems to make it weird.

Similarly I have something elsewhere like
$$
\sum_{k,l,m=1}^n a_{ik}a_{kl}b_{lm}T_{kmj}.
$$
Again you would normally want this to be the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of a product but it doesn't seem to quite work???

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\d{{\vec\delta}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Take the standard Kronecker delta symbol
$$\eqalign{
\delta_{ij} &= \begin{cases}
{\tt1}\qquad {\rm if}\;i=j \\
0\qquad {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
}$$
and extend it to three indices
$$\eqalign{
\d_{ijk} &= \begin{cases}
{\tt1}\qquad {\rm if}\;i=j=k \\
0\qquad {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
}$$
This extended Kronecker delta can be used to restore the usual Einstein convention
$$\eqalign{
B_{ij} &= A_{il}\d_{lkm}\d_{mpq}T_{pqj} \qiq B_{ij}=\sum_k A_{ik}T_{kkj} \\
}$$
This result can also be written without indices
by using explicit single/double-dot products
$$\eqalign{
B &= A\cdot\d\cdot\d:T \\
}$$